# How to connect to flash media server in flex 4 using actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, amazon-ec2, flex4, flash-builder

I am totally new to Adobe (Flash) Media server, We are using Flash Media Server on Amazon EC2 instance, and i can browse the default page of the media server with no problem. I am also using Flash Builder (flex 4.6) to connect to the server. Here is my code:

```
        private function connect():void {
            nc = new NetConnection();
            nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netStatusHandler);
            nc.connect("rtmp://000.000.000.000/applications/vod/");
            mic =Microphone.getMicrophone();
            mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
            mic.setSilenceLevel(0);
            cam = Camera.getCamera();
        }
```

But it cant connect to the server, any comment? 
Just wondering if my rtmp address is correct, how can I check it outside of my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong with the netconnection location. I created a new folder in rootinstall/applications/ and called it testfolder and gave it write permission:

```
    nc.connect("rtmp://000.000.000.000/testfolder");
```

Answer (score 0):

just try with

```
nc.connect("rtmp://000.000.000.000/vod/fileName.f4v");
```

make sure your FMS is running on default port, if you assign any custom port then include it in the url.

Comment: its running on default port. problem is still there.I want to capture webcam video and save it. do you know alternative way to do so?

Comment: In the question you used applications/testfolder, where as applications would be your webapps folder, that means u just need to call your testfolder after the ip address.   similar to nc.connect("rtmp://000.000.000.000/vod/fileName.f4v");

Answer (score 0):

In the question you used like

```
nc.connect("rtmp://000.000.000.000/applications/vod/");
```

applications is not required as it represents your webapps folder. you just need to add

```
nc.connect("rtmp://000.000.000.000/vod/
```

this should connect to your media server.